# How To Disallow Special Characters And Digits On Jquery

Tags: digits

I want to disallow **Special Characters** and **Digits** on my textbox. But i dont want to do it by allowing **[a-zA-Z]**. Because this regex expression doesn't contain all chars(like turkish language chars). Thats why i choose the way **disallowing** and not **allowing** :)

Here the code i tried;

```
$('#Testtextbox').bind('keypress', function (event) {
        var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9]+$");
        var regex2 = new RegExp("/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.':*?<>{}]/g");
        var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
        if (regex.test(key) || regex2.test(key)) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

This code disallowing digits. But it doesn't work on special characters.

Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by using below code.

```
$('#Testtextbox').bind('keypress', function (event) {
        var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-ZşŞıİçÇöÖüÜĞğ. ]+$");
        var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);

        if (!regex.test(key)) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

The problem caused of making mistake while creating regex expression.